# Should I purchase two lock cylinders to create a double-sided lock?

Tags: doors, lock

I have a deadbolt that I would like to replace.  On each side of the door it looks like:

[image]

Does one buy two of these for a door or is this another product?

Comment: Are you sure you wish to keep it keyed on both sides?

Comment: Yes I would like both sides keyed.  Thank you

Comment: You purchase a different unit, not two.  You’re looking for “double cylinder deadbolt”.

Comment: It may be  a code violation to have the inside keyed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to *replace* the deadbolt unit (as stated in the question), usually the most economical option is to remove the entire assembly including the faceplates, keyed cylinders, and the deadbolt itself (the part that inserts into the edge of the door) and replace all with a new unit.

Another option is to have the two cylinders rekeyed, if a new key is all that is desired.

Your picture, which looks like it was grabbed from the web rather than being an actual photo of **your** lock, shows a specialty commercial style lock cylinder. If it is a true representation of your hardware you should visit a locksmith or commercial door and lock supplier.